# Python Socket Receive all the bytes/data

Tags: python

I have this code intended to connect to a domain and return the data:

```
import socket
import ssl

def http_socket(domain='www.google.com', port=80):
    client = socket.socket()
    host = socket.gethostbyname(domain)
    client.connect((host, port))
    client.sendall("GET /\r\n")
    response = client.recv(10000)
    return response
```

From what I've understood `client.recv(10000)` expects an integer of the response html to return in terms of string length. I'd prefer to get the whole back.

**Note:** You'd probably ask if I would use *BeautifulSoup* (I'd likely do that) but for penetration test I'm following through and confirming if the `socket` module code works and how it plays along in the upcoming big picture.

Comment: 10000 is just the buffer size. If you get less data your will still receive them. Btw. BeautifulSoup doesn't handle data transport, it is only for parsing HTML.

Comment: Your example works for me (modulo the need for a bytes object rather than string in python3 in the sendall() call). What exactly is the problem?